# Update/refresh Custom Control to reflect new data

Tags: abap, dynpro

I am using `CL_GUI_CUSTOM_CONTROL` and `CL_GUI_ABAPEDIT`. On the initial execution, it is working fine. However, when using user command the custom control/abap editor is not reflecting the updated data. I tried debugging, the data in the background was updated but not on the display. Tried also the `CL_GUI_CFW=>FLUSH` but it didn’t work. Hoping to gain some help here.

Comment: It's impossible to know what is your issue because you didn't post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's probably the classic issue that you are creating the same control again and again, only the first one is shown: if you change the other(s), they are not shown. Instead, you must create only one instance of the control. The refresh may not be needed, it depends. In the worst case, a CL_GUI_CFW=>UPDATE_VIEW would suffice.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I should have just replaced the data instead of re-instantiating the class.